# Multiple Definitions error everywhere, how do I fix this?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, makefile

**This is my Makefile:**

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c) \
          $(wildcard src/utils/*.c)
obj = $(SRC:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS =

output: $(obj)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(obj): $(SRC)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(obj) main
```

**This is main.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "utils/activations.h"

double check();

int main(){
        check();
}

double check(){
        double output = act(0.2, "sigmoid");
        return output;

}
```

**This is activations.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

double act();
double relu();
double sigmoid();
double tan_h();

double act(double x, char actFunc[]){
        double y;

        if(actFunc == "relu"){
                y = relu(x);
        }
        if(actFunc == "sigmoid"){
                y = sigmoid(x);
        }
        if(actFunc == "tanh"){
                y = tan_h(x);
        }

        return y;
}

double relu(double input){
        double output;
        if(input < 0){
                output = 0;
        } else{

                output = input;
        }
        return output;

}

double sigmoid(double  input){
        return 1/(1+exp(-1*input));
}

double tan_h(double input){
        return tanh(input);
}
```

**Ok so this is the error:**

```
gcc src/main.c src/utils/activations.c -o src/utils/activations.o  
gcc src/main.o src/utils/activations.o -o output 
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/main.o: in function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/main.o: in function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/main.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x90): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/main.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x150): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xc0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/main.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:21: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x90): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x150): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xc0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:main.c:(.text+0x180): multiple definition of `main'; src/main.o:main.c:(.text+0x180): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:main.c:(.text+0x199): multiple definition of `check'; src/main.o:main.c:(.text+0x199): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `act'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.text+0x1c0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.text+0x21c): multiple definition of `relu'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.text+0x21c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.text+0x24b): multiple definition of `sigmoid'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.text+0x24b): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.text+0x274): multiple definition of `tan_h'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.text+0x274): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_crt0':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/cygwin_crt0.c:18: multiple definition of `cygwin_crt0'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/cygwin_crt0.c:18: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_premain0':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain0.c:13: multiple definition of `cygwin_premain0'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain0.c:13: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_premain1':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain1.c:13: multiple definition of `cygwin_premain1'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain1.c:13: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_premain2':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain2.c:13: multiple definition of `cygwin_premain2'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain2.c:13: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_premain3':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain3.c:13: multiple definition of `cygwin_premain3'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/premain3.c:13: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_crt0_common@8':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/_cygwin_crt0_common.cc:91: multiple definition of `_cygwin_crt0_common@8'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/_cygwin_crt0_common.cc:91: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_dll_entry@12':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_entry.c:15: multiple definition of `_cygwin_dll_entry@12'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_entry.c:15: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_noncygwin_dll_entry@12':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_entry.c:15: multiple definition of `_cygwin_noncygwin_dll_entry@12'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_entry.c:15: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `DllMain@12':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_main.cc:35: multiple definition of `DllMain@12'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/dll_main.cc:35: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `pei386_runtime_relocator':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/pseudo-reloc-dummy.c:10: multiple definition of `_pei386_runtime_relocator'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/pseudo-reloc-dummy.c:10: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o: in function `cygwin_attach_dll':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/cygwin_attach_dll.c:19: multiple definition of `cygwin_attach_dll'; src/main.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/cygwin_attach_dll.c:19: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `__RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `_data_start__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x82c): multiple definition of `__DTOR_LIST__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x82c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x294): multiple definition of `__cxa_atexit'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x294): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x798): multiple definition of `free'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x798): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x108): multiple definition of `_nm___impure_ptr'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x108): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xc0): multiple definition of `_imp__tanh'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xc0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__tls_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `_rt_psrelocs_start'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa0): multiple definition of `_imp__cygwin_detach_dll'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xl_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xi_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xi_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `__dynamically_loaded'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x800): multiple definition of `dll_dllcrt0'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x800): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x808): multiple definition of `GetModuleHandleA@4'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x808): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x100): multiple definition of `hmod_libgcc'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x100): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_bss_start__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `__RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x1c): multiple definition of `environ'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x1c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xac): multiple definition of `_imp__exp'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xac): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xd0): multiple definition of `_imp__GetProcAddress@8'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xd0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xp_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xp_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb8): multiple definition of `_imp__posix_memalign'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb8): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xc8): multiple definition of `_imp__FreeLibrary@4'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xc8): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x98): multiple definition of `_imp___impure_ptr'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x98): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xdc): multiple definition of `_IAT_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xdc): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x790): multiple definition of `cygwin_internal'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x790): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `_RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.data+0x40): multiple definition of `_data_end__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.data+0x40): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x820): multiple definition of `_CTOR_LIST__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x820): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x104): multiple definition of `_bss_end__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x104): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xc_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x29c): multiple definition of `__main'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x29c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xc_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x7a8): multiple definition of `posix_memalign'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x7a8): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x238): multiple definition of `_lib32_libkernel32_a_iname'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x238): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x820): multiple definition of `__CTOR_LIST__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x820): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x780): multiple definition of `calloc'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x780): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `_fmode'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x21c): multiple definition of `cygwin1_dll_iname'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x21c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x0): multiple definition of `_head_cygwin1_dll'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x90): multiple definition of `_imp____main'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x90): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x7b0): multiple definition of `realloc'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x7b0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb4): multiple definition of `_imp__malloc'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x788): multiple definition of `cygwin_detach_dll'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x788): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa8): multiple definition of `_imp__dll_dllcrt0'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa8): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x2a4): multiple definition of `exp'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x2a4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xbc): multiple definition of `_imp__realloc'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xbc): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x8c): multiple definition of `_IAT_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x8c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x94): multiple definition of `_imp___dll_crt0@0'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x94): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xcc): multiple definition of `_imp__GetModuleHandleA@4'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xcc): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x7a0): multiple definition of `malloc'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x7a0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x82c): multiple definition of `_DTOR_LIST__'; src/main.o:cygming-crtend.c:(.text+0x82c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x8c): multiple definition of `_imp____cxa_atexit'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x8c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xt_start__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x9c): multiple definition of `_imp__calloc'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x9c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa4): multiple definition of `_imp__cygwin_internal'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xa4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__tls_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.data+0x20): multiple definition of `__cygwin_cxx_malloc'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.data+0x20): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:fake:(.text+0x2ac): multiple definition of `tanh'; src/main.o:fake:(.text+0x2ac): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb0): multiple definition of `_imp__free'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xb0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'; /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x14): multiple definition of `_head_lib32_libkernel32_a'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0x14): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `_rt_psrelocs_end'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xd4): multiple definition of `_imp__LoadLibraryA@4'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.idata+0xd4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): multiple definition of `_RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__'; src/main.o:activations.c:(.rdata+0x304): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/utils/activations.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): multiple definition of `__crt_xt_end__'; src/main.o:crt0.c:(.rsrc+0x0): first defined here
make: *** [Makefile:9: output] Error 1
```

I am new to Makefiles, and sorta familiar with C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget/omit compiling object files. Your get executable on the first step. So you don't need the rule `$(obj): $(SRC)`.

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c) \
          $(wildcard src/utils/*.c)
obj = $(SRC:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS =

output: $(SRC)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(obj) output
```

If you wish to compile object files see bellow

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/utils/*.c)
obj = $(SRC:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS =

output: $(obj)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c $(SRC)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(obj) main
```

Comment: Thank you so much @S.M , however I am struggling to understand, what is the difference between the following: 
1. `%.o: %.c`
2. `%.o: %.c $(SRC)`
3. `$(obj): $(SRC)`

Thanks,
Syeam

Comment: 1. You missed `-c` (compile w/o link). 2. You can't compile several files to one object file, so each .c should be compiled to one .o file.

Answer (score 0):

The linker tells you that you have more definitions of **X** than you should, and you should have only one. In such scenarios you have to track down where those additional definitions might be defined. In this simple project it's quite easy, look at the commands you use to compile and link:

```
output: $(obj)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(obj): $(SRC)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

In *gcc* you can go two ways:

- compile in one step and link in another step (this is what you want),
- compile and link in the same step (this is what you've actually done).

You have compiled and linked in the same step two times. The first goal (`$(obj): $(SRC)`) compiled and linked your executable and then your second goal tried to linked something that's already linked.

You can now either remove the unnecessary linking goal, or tell *gcc* in the compiling goal that you want to compile the files only, because you will link them later (`-c` flag).

#### Separate compiling and linking

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/utils/*.c)
obj = $(SRC:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS =

output: $(obj)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(obj): $(SRC)
        $(CC) -c $^

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(obj) main
```

#### Compile and link at once

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/utils/*.c)
obj = $(SRC:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS =

output: $(SRC)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(obj) main
```